# Identical mount points for the same partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I was installing Ubuntu using the mini ISO image and I ran into the following error when partitioning my disk:

```
        Identical mount points for two file systems
Two file systems are assigned the same mount point (/boot/efi): SCSI1
(0,0,0), partition #1 (SDA) and SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition 1 (SDA).
Please correct this by changing mount points.
```

Only partition 1 is set to mount to `/boot/efi`. I also have partition 8 which is 200 GB where Ubuntu is going eventually, mounted to `/`

Comment: Additionally,  should I be safe to abort installation at this point?

Comment: Few questions, how far into installation were you, At the partitioning menu or After or Far After? Did you preform a disc check before installing? Was it connected to internet during install? I had similar but not identical issues with uefi and partitioning for RAID with Ubuntu Server 14.04, trick was to boot into Legacy mode then star the install.

Comment: I was at the partition screen, and when I tried to go further, this error happened. I was online while installing

Comment: I am safely out of installation, no harm done.

Comment: I got a similar message reinstalling 18.10, although on my system at least the partitions were different to each other.  Neither of the volumes are actually mounted.  Explicitly mapping them in fstab and running mount -a did not make it go away.  (Is that not what it's asking for?)  I'm suspicious that it actually hit some other problem and is showing an inaccurate error message.